# implementing a typelist in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates, metaprogramming

I'm studying metaprogramming in C++ with templates and I'm trying to implement a typelist, and operations on it.

I'm defining a typelist as a variadic class template and operations as templated structs with partial specializations. Operations like Front, PopFront and PushFront work fine, but when I instantiate Back and Element (to index the typelist to get the n-th element), the compiler complains that I'm using an incomplete type:

```
/**** typelist ****/
template <typename... Types>
struct Typelist
{
};

/**** get first element ****/
template <typename List>
struct Front;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Front<Typelist<Head,Tail...>>
{
    typedef Head type;
};

template <typename List>
using FrontT = typename Front<List>::type;

/**** pop first element ***/
template <typename List>
struct PopFront;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct PopFront<Typelist<Head,Tail...>>
{
    using type = Typelist<Tail...>;
};

template <typename List>
using PopFrontT = typename PopFront<List>::type;

/**** push first element ****/
template <typename List, typename Element>
struct PushFront;

template <typename... Elements, typename Element>
struct PushFront<Typelist<Elements...>,Element>
{
    using type = Typelist<Element,Elements...>;
};

template <typename List, typename Element>
using PushFrontT = typename PushFront<List,Element>::type;

/**** get last element ****/ 
template <typename List>
struct Back;

template <typename... Head, typename Tail>
struct Back<Typelist<Head...,Tail>>
{
    typedef Tail type;
};

/**** indexing ****/
template <typename List, unsigned Index>           // recursive case
struct Element
{
    using type = typename Element<typename PopFront<List>::type, Index - 1>::type;
};

template <typename List>
struct Element<List,0>                             // base case
{
    typedef typename Front<List>::type type;
};

// template <typename... Types>                        // base case
// struct Element<Typelist<Types...>,0>
// {
//     using type = typename Front<Typelist<Types...>>::type;
// };

// template <typename... Types, unsigned Index>        // recursive case
// struct Element<Typelist<Types...>,Index>
// {
//     using type = typename Element<typename PopFront<Typelist<Types...>>::type, Index - 1>::type;
// };

template <typename List, unsigned Index>
struct ElementI : ElementI<PopFrontT<List>,Index - 1>
{
};

template <typename List>
struct ElementI<List,0> : Front<List>
{
};

template <typename List, unsigned Index>
using ElementT = typename Element<List,Index>::type;
```

I understand that I can use template parameter packs for any parameter in partial specializations as long as arguments can be deduced, so I think the declaration is correct, right?

**EDIT**
Element now works, I made a spelling mistake calling it, Back still doesn't, and I can't understand why.

**EDIT**
this is the code to test the typelist and the compiler (GCC 7.2) error (I slightly changed the implementation of typelist):

**EDIT EDIT** compiler is GCC 7.2

```
#include "typelist.hpp"
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Typelist<int, double, bool> tl;

    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Front<decltype(tl)>::type,int>::value, "not same");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename PopFront<decltype(tl)>::type,Typelist<double,bool>>::value, "not same");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename PushFront<decltype(tl),float>::type,Typelist<float,int,double,bool>>::value, "not same");
    /* compiler error */ static_assert(std::is_same<typename Back<decltype(tl)>::type,bool>::value, "not same");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename ElementI<decltype(tl),0>::type,int>::value, "not same");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename ElementI<decltype(tl),1>::type,double>::value, "not same");
    static_assert(std::is_same<ElementT<decltype(tl),2>,bool>::value, "not same");

    return 0;
}


main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:11:61: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Back<Typelist<int, double, bool> >'
     static_assert(std::is_same<typename Back<decltype(tl)>::type,bool>::value, "not same");
                                                             ^~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
typelist.hpp:48:8: note: declaration of 'struct Back<Typelist<int, double, bool> >'
 struct Back;
        ^~~~
main.cpp:11:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     static_assert(std::is_same<typename Back<decltype(tl)>::type,bool>::value, "not same");
```

Comment: Please paste the compilation error you're getting and with which compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `clang++` (Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)) I get the following message:

```
t.cpp:51:8: error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
struct Back<Typelist<Head...,Tail>>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:50:23: note: non-deducible template parameter 'Head'
template <typename... Head, typename Tail>
                      ^
t.cpp:50:38: note: non-deducible template parameter 'Tail'
template <typename... Head, typename Tail>
                                     ^
```

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack (sorry i don't have a primary ref)

> In a primary class template, the template parameter pack must be the final parameter in the template parameter list.
>   In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments, or have default arguments:

```
template<typename... Ts, typename U> struct Invalid; // Error: Ts.. not at the end

template<typename ...Ts, typename U, typename=void>
void valid(U, Ts...);     // OK: can deduce U
// void valid(Ts..., U);  // Can't be used: Ts... is a non-deduced context in this position

valid(1.0, 1, 2, 3);      // OK: deduces U as double, Ts as {int,int,int}
```

But we can solve the issue by defining `Back` in terms of `Element`.

```
/**** get last element ****/
template <typename List>
struct Back;

template <typename... Args>
struct Back<Typelist<Args...>>
{
    using type = typename Element<Typelist<Args...>, sizeof...(Args) - 1>::type;
};
```

Question:

Why do you have `template using` statements for all your types except `Back` and `Element`?

Comment: It's just an exercise to learn typelists and tmp, so some things may be missing.
Why is it a non-deduced context? It could always use all the arguments except the last one to deduce the pack. Same with typelist argument

Comment: @Luca I don't know this for a fact so this is speculation. When building a compiler you try and build it to be as close to LALR(1) as this makes it easier to write. This means you would prefer to only look ahead at most one token in the lexical input stream to make the choice of what grammer is being expanded. If you allow the tuple expansion pack to be the head of `<Head...,Tail>` you can't tell where to stop the grammer expression for `Head` without looking forward 3 tokens (and this could get arbitrarily complex if you expand to the rest of the syntax).

Comment: Thus parameter pack expansions must be at the end of grammer expressions to maintain a 1 lexeme look ahead (or as close to one as possible). Now C++ is already an extremely complicated language to parse so when adding this feature they have just decided that we don't want to allow arbitrarily complex grammers (especially things that will blow up compile time). So where do you cut off the grammer? Do you cut it off at zero/one expression after the pack? or do you allow arbitrary number of expressions after the pack. I think this is a design decision to kept the compiler complexity to a minimum.

Comment: I was just wondering if that is indeed the reason, the parser being greedy.